# "NameError: name [module] is not defined" when importing module in class

Tags: python

I have the following test code:

```
import sqlite3

class database:
    def __init__(self, name):
        self.name = name

    def connect(name):
        db = sqlite3.connect("%s.db" % self.name)
        c = db.cursor()

    def test(self):
        print (3)
```

If I run `database('name').test()`, I get `3`, so that works. But if I try `database('name').connect()`, I get, "NameError: name 'sqlite3' is not defined"

Classes are relatively new to me and I'm still trying to figure out how they work. Thanks much for any help.

EDIT: See the comments in the answer the the solution. The problem seems to be that I was importing sqlite3 in both the file and the notebook. The solution was to import the module only in the file.

Comment: It does not explain your error, but I think that should be: `db = sqlite3.connect("%s.db" % self.name)`

Comment: you're right, thanks for pointing out

Comment: And you are missing the `self` parameter in the `connect` method. Should be: `def connect(self, name):`.

Comment: You are calling name in your method, but you assign `self.name`.
Just choose the one you want to keep.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You may have a typo somewhere in your description, because I think you would get another error first when doing

```
data = database()
data.test()
data.connect('name')
```

You need to add the `self` to the connect def to make it a proper class method. There's also a typo in the connect call. The following should work

```
import sqlite3

class database:
    def __init__(self, name):
        self.name = name

    def connect(self):
        db = sqlite3.connect("%s.db" % self.name)
        c = db.cursor()

    def test(self):
        print(3)
```

then do

```
data = database('test')
data.connect()
```

Comment: You're right that I had a typo in the description, which was sloppy on my part; apologies for that. But I'm *still* getting this same error when using that code verbatim (save for replacing 'test' with the name of my db). It keeps telling me it doesn't recognize the name sqlite3.

Comment: you are sure that you imported it in your current python session?

Comment: imported in both the file where the class is created and inside the jupyter notebook I'm running that class in. That's why it's so frustrating :(

Comment: @snapcrack I suggest restarting your Jupyter kernel. You've probably polluted your namespace somehow.

Comment: you only need to import `sqlite3` in the file that defines the class, which you are then importing into your Jupyter notebook. Maybe double check that you are importing the class from the correct file, maybe you have a second one without the sqlite3 import and import the class from there by accident

Comment: @juanpa.arrivillaga you and Sebastian were both right, it works now. Sebastian go ahead and add that to your answer and I'll accept